# MySQL delete records with cross foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, entity

I have a doubt. I have two tables InnoDB in a MySQL, this is their entities:

```
class Account
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * one account is created by one user
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="createdby", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $createdby;
.
.
.
```

And

```
class User
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 *  Many Users belong to One Account
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Account", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $account;
```

So there are two different relationships, one is the "account created by a user" and the other is "user belongs to an account".

When I try to delete an account (pe. DELETE FROM account WHERE id = 28) I would like to delete also the user who has created the account. I'm not saying delete the user who belongs to this account, just the one who has created it. But it gives me a foreign key constraint error:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`example`.`user`, CONSTRAINT `FK_8D93D6497D3656A4` FOREIGN KEY (`account`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`)) in ...

Any advise?

Thanks.

Comment: I would advise you to model your two entities after a tutorial site or documentation.  I see multiple problems with how you setup the relationships, but as I have never used this ORM framework before, I'm out for now.

Comment: Thanks for your timeTim.

Comment: Tim, what kind of advise is to read the documentation?. Firstly, do you understand what I'm asking?,  Secondly, is it reasonable to say you see multiple problems if you have never used this ORM?. Why you have deleted all the posts we have writen?. They could give other people the posibility to help me. As I said, thanks for your time.

Comment: What I am saying is to model/compare your code against an example which used a many to one relationship.  As for my deleted answer, anyone else can see it.  By the way, you have both entities marked as many to one, and that doesn't look right to me.

Comment: OK, let's talk about the "created by" relationship. An account has to be created by one user, that's clear. So here we have a one-to-one relationship. But it is not exclusive, could be the case that an user has created various accounts, so is a Many-to-one relationship from the point of view of the account entity. Now let's talk about the "belongs to an account", an account can hold many users so is a many-to-one relationship from the point of view of the user entiry. Boths are unidirectional because the logic of the application doesn't needs to.

Comment: Before asking here I have spend all this morning making tests with all the examples I found, but unfortunatly none of the examples I found were about two entities with cross relationships. Do you know where I can find such example?

Comment: Can an account own many users?  Or is each account always associated with a single user?  Who is the owner in the relationship, a user or an account

Comment: Let me insist, there are two relationships. An account owns one or more users (1) but is created only by one of his users (2), by the first user. One user is only owned by one account. This last has slighly changed from my previous comment, thus tonight I have been thinking and there is no reason to complicate more the model. Searching I have found that this is called Circular Dependency, and I'm seeing how to deal with this situation.

Comment: Circular dependency sounds like a hack to me.  Keep it simple; use one-to-many (or many-to-one) or possibly many-to-many.

Comment: After a good reading the advise for people who finds this post is to avoid Circular Dependencies. There are different ways to do it, just google Circular Dependencies and you will find the appropiate way for your logic. In my case I will treat the CreatedBy field not as a relation and perform the logic in the code.